# Dynamic CRM 2011 5 developers 5 databases - how to sync solutions

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, collaboration, methodology

We are 5 developers working today with **1** database.
We have always one ASYNC service working in order to allow debugging, it means that when a developer wants to debug async, he announce to the others that he is hijacking the async service to his machine till he finishes the debugging.
We want to switch to a database per developer, there are a lot of issues with that, for example syncing schema changes / solutions with other programmers/

What is the best practice with large team of developers, is there any tool / methodology that is best for large teams.
Also, in general, what is the best practice for large teams developing Dynamic CRM 2011.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Highly recommended reference:** Microsoft released a very thorough whitepaper on Lifecycle management. Read about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2013/05/17/release-alm-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-crm-solution-lifecycle-management.aspx).

A typical **development** flow could be

- Developers develop against their own personal development organization (Online/On-premise), in a solution with the same publisher / name
- They export the developer solution
- They unpack the zip file into the XML structure
- And check it into source control, merging it with the master version

A typical **deployment into the integration organization** could be

- Get a latest version of the XML structure from source control
- Package it into a .zip solution
- Import it into the integration organization

This way, you have a full history of all changes, linked to the developers, and you can make controlled merges, using merging tools you're familiar with.

A developer can always get a latest version from source control, package it and deploy it in his own development organization.

Comment: Great white paper.  I'm going to have to take some time to digest that.

Comment: It's a great read. You'll have a lot of different options written out for you there. I wonder why they only released it this late.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, I have worked/advised the following:

- All devs work on their own virtual system.  Much easier debugging.  No trampling on or coordinating with others.  I use VirtualBox.
- Work is exported (unmanaged solutions) into a common build system.
- Work is merged into the relevant managed solution(s) in build.
- Managed solution(s) exported from build and applied to test / uat / pre-production etc.
- Managed solution(s) applied to production environment.